# how to replace commas of fetchall with three columns in psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have to fetch 3 columns from a table using fetchall, i need to write it into a text file without commas.

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
con = psycopg2.connect(database="dbname",user="postgres",password="pwd",host="localhost",port= '5432')
cursor_obj = con.cursor()
sql = f"""SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM TABLE WHERE COL1= %S, COL3 = 1 ORDER BY COL1,COL2,COL3 ASC;"""
row = cursor_obj.execute(d1,)
resultset = cursor_obj.fetchall()
resultset[len(resultset)] = resultset[len(resultset)].str.replace(',','')
```

I have to write the no comma col1 col2 col3 into a text file getting Index error: List out of range. Please guide

Comment: `resultset[len(resultset)]` Python list indexes start at zero.  So if the length of a list is 5, then the valid indexes are 0-4.  Index 5 does not exist.

Comment: `row = cursor_obj.execute(d1,)` Also, what is `d1`?  That variable is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:
`resultset[len(resultset)] = resultset[len(resultset)].str.replace(',','')`

I have modified your code:

```
list_data = [list(_val) for _val in resultset]
fnl_data = [[str(_val) for _val in _data] for _data in list_data]
```

After that you can open the `txt` file and insert those list values -

```
with open("yourtextfile.txt", "w") as f:
    for _val in fnl_data:
        f.write("\t".join(_val) + "\n")
```